Hover button with javascript
I'm trying to make a hover-able button with javascript. It works but the onmouseout function hide the div to soon. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
I know you can use CSS to this but i would like to use javascript


function show() {
  let div = document.getElementById("cloth");
  div.setAttribute("style", "display:block; border:1px solid black;");
}

function hide() {
  let div = document.getElementById("cloth");
  div.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
}
.dropA {
  display: block;
}

.cloths {
  display: none;
}
<div>
  <button id="menu" class="dropA"  onmouseover="show()">
    Menu
  </button>
  <div id="cloth"   class="cloths" onmouseout="hide()">
    <p>Dresses</p>
    <p>Shirts</p>
    <p>Pants</p>
  </div>
</div>




Hovering "Dresses" counts as a mouse out on "cloths" (note that "clothes" is the usual spelling).  Consider using mouseleave event instead of mouseout.

You need to add on button#menu this onmouseout="hide()" and on div#cloth this onmouseover="show()"  (because  when you leave the button or menu you want to close the menu and when you are on the button or on the menu to show menu

Well i updated my answer on the other post. Yeah i saw that as soon as i go over the  element it exits. Tried to fix it with z-index in the hopes that i could hide the element. But yeah no luck. Is there anyway to do this without using CSS?

Just out of curiosity, why you don't want to use CSS :hover?

Please refer to this example for a more accessible and semantically correct way to execute the pattern of a button dropdown menu: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menu-button/examples/menu-button-links/

@RokoC.Buljan javascript is my strong point.  I tried using the :hover method with parent and child. I feel like its going to require a lot of CSS to add multiple drop down tabs. I think its the way I will end up going. Wanted to see if i could work around using CSS and just edit the style with setAttribute.

You also need to use some correct HTML tags, for a menu you should use <menu> with <li> elements -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu

You can't do it this way, because a mouseout event occurs every time your mouse enters one of the <p> elements it contains (the mouse is no longer on your div#cloth, it is on a p).
If you want to keep this logic you should use a pointerleave event.
see pointerleave event
Also, prefer to use js addEventListener() method, instead of DOM.element.property methods.


const 
  eMenu  = document.querySelector('#menu')
, eCloth = document.querySelector('#cloth')
  ;
eMenu.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) =>
  {
  eCloth.classList.remove('noDisplay');
  });
eCloth.addEventListener('pointerleave', (e) =>
  {
  eCloth.classList.add('noDisplay');
  });
#cloth {
  border  : 1px solid green;
  padding : 0 1em;
  width   : fit-content;
  }
#cloth p {
  background : yellow;
  cursor     : pointer;
  }
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}
<div>
  <button id="menu" >
    Menu
  </button>
  <div id="cloth" class="noDisplay" >
    <p>Dresses</p>
    <p>Shirts</p>
    <p>Pants</p>
  </div>
</div>




Also, by using IDs you're limited to one component only in a single page.

The UI is still bad. The users has to hover over the dropdown in order to close it.

@RokoC.Buljan your comments are true, but the OP seems to be a beginner with HTML-CSS-JS; and I'm not going to modify his code further...

Alright will give it a go.

eCloth.classList.remove('noDisplay'); Could you explain this one to me

@Smiley_Guy by default in HTML a <div> is already in display: block; an easy way to make it disappear is to add a new class containing a display: none;, which I have here called noDisplay (defined here in the CSS); then remove this class name to display your div again and let the default display take effect. See .remove() method



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pools</title>
</head>
<style>
    .dropA {
        display:block;
    }
    .cloths {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
    <div onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide()">
        <button id="menu" class="dropA">Menu</button>
        <div id="cloth" class="cloths">
            
            <p>Dresses</p>
            <p>Shirts</p>
            <p>Pants</p>
            
        </div>
    </div>
   <script>
    function show()
    {
        let div=document.getElementById("cloth");
        div.setAttribute("style","display:block; border:1px solid black;");
    }
    function hide()
    {
        let div=document.getElementById("cloth");
        div.setAttribute("style","display:none;");
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>




Good answers include some explanation, not just code

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
